# Is there an official description of all the OOTB site definitions?

Tags: 2013, site-template, site-definition

Does a detailed definition of all the out of the box site definitions exist? If it's a book, please let me know what book, but I want something more descriptive than a one sentence description and the site definition name. Specifically, what features are included and activated, what list definitions are included, workflows, etc. What are *all* the differences between BLANKINTERNET#2 and CMSPUBLISHING#0, for example?

Answer (score -1):

IMP LINK : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20100.sharepoint-2010-default-site-templates.aspx

CMSPUBLISHING#0 : A blank site for expanding your Web site and 
quickly publishing Web pages. Contributors 
can work on draft versions of pages and publish 
them to make them visible to readers. 
The site includes  document and image libraries 
for storing Web publishing assets.

BLANKINTERNET2:A site for publishing Web pages on a schedule 
by using approval workflows. It includes document 
and image libraries for storing Web publishing assets. 
By default, only sites with this template can be 
created under this site

Comment: I don't need a definition of "site definition", and I asked for "something more descriptive than a one sentence description... specifically, what features are included and activated", and this is tagged with 2013.

Comment: ok google , you will get the right book .